# Cross Correlating each pair column of matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, cross-correlation

I have a problem when I want to do cross correlating two matrices in matlab. The code looks like this:

```
load a.dat
load b.dat
x1 = a(:,m)
x2 = b(:,m)
m = 1:3;
for m=1:3;
x = xcrorr(x1,x2);
end
```

Both a and b are (1500 x 3) matrices, I want to cross correlate each column and get the value in 3 columns, i.e. as same as the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
load a.dat
load b.dat
for m=1:3
  x1 = a(:,m);
  x2 = b(:,m);
  x(:,m) = xcorr(x1,x2);
end
```

which you could shorten to:

```
load a.dat
load b.dat
for m=1:3
  x(:,m) = xcorr(a(:,m),b(:,m));
end
```